# Error: React Context is unavailable in Server Components using "use clinent"

Tags: next.js13

I'm been working on auth is there any error in my code. Please help how to fix this issue my brain is not working right now

```
"use client"



import { Session } from "next-auth"; 
import { SessionProvider as Provider} from "next-auth/react";




type Props ={
children: React.ReactNode;
session: Session | null;
};





export function SessionProvider({children, session }: Props) {

return (
  <Provider>
    {children}
  </Provider>
);
};
```

I did tried using "use client" but it didn't worked

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.